# Cannot recognize word if spaced by tab

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have problem on that the program cannot read each word if words in text file is spaced by tab, not space.

For example, here is file.

**part_Q.txt:**

```
NWLR35MQ        649
HCDA93OW        526
abc 1
def 2
ghi 3
```

- note that between "abc" and "1", there is a tab, not space.
- Also note that between "NWLR35MQ" and "649", there is no tab but all are spaces. same for 2nd line as well.

**Output:**

```
NWLR35MQ
649
HCDA93OW
526
def
2
ghi
3
```

However, if I replace tab between "abc" and "1" by space in the file, then it outputs correctly like below,

**Expected output:**

```
NWLR35MQ
649
HCDA93OW
526
abc
1
def
2
ghi
3
```

It correctly display all words in file. How can I display all words regardless of tab or space? it should display all words in both cases. It seems that the program regards tab as a character.

**Below is source code:**

```
#!/bin/sh

tempCtr=0
realCtr=0
copyCtr=0
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
   IFS=' '
   tempCtr=0
   for word in $line; do
    temp[$tempCtr]="$word"
    let "tempCtr++"
   done 
   # if there are exactly 2 fields in each line, store ID and quantity
   if [ $tempCtr -eq 2 ]
   then
    part_Q[$realCtr]=${temp[$copyCtr]}
    let "realCtr++"
    let "copyCtr++"
    part_Q[$realCtr]=${temp[$copyCtr]}
    let "realCtr++"
    copyCtr=0
   fi
done < part_Q.txt

for value in "${part_Q[@]}"; do
    echo $value
done
```

Comment: Just an idea: you could try to pre-process file (or line) and replace tab by space. BTW `awk` definitely won't have such problem.

Comment: Change `IFS=' '` to `IFS=$'\t '` but do consider `awk`

Comment: Just remove `IFS=` and `IFS=' '`. `read line` line will read a line regardless of the presence of white spaces. `for word in $line` will word split by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `IFS=' '` to `IFS=$'\t '` solved the problem.

Comment: Unnecessary use of `IFS`. It will work even without setting it at all. The default value of IFS is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You might solve this (as in your example) by a single line of code

```
cat part_Q.txt | tr $'\t' $'\n' | tr -s ' ' $'\n'
```

which

- first `tr`anslates a tab into a newline, and then
- `tr`anslates space(`-s`) as well

Note: For `tr` you will need the `$` before the `\t`ab and `\n`ewline characters in bash.

---

Since it has been mentioned, `awk` can help, too:

```
awk 'NF==2{print $1"\n"$2}' part_Q.txt
```

Where `NF==2` even takes care about only using lines with 2 'words'.

Comment: UUOC when you can `awk 'NF==2{print $1"\n"$2}' part_Q.txt`.

Comment: adjusted, thanks. used the pipe by copy/paste from tr example

Comment: You don't need `cat` there either.  `tr $'\t' $'\n' <part_Q.txt`

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? If outputting is your only goal, this can be achieved very easily:

```
$ cat <<EOF | sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]+/\n/'
NWLR35MQ        649
HCDA93OW        526
abc 1
def 2
ghi 3
EOF

NWLR35MQ
649
HCDA93OW
526
abc
1
def
2
ghi
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk is faster than a loop, but here is how you can implement this with a loop:

```
realCtr=0
while read -r x1 x2 x3; do
   if [ -n "${x2}" ] && [ -z "${x3}" ]; then
      echo 2=$x2
    part_Q[realCtr]="${x1}"
   (( realCtr++ ))
    part_Q[realCtr]="${x2}"
   (( realCtr++ ))
   fi
done  < part_Q.txt

echo "Array (2 items each line):"
echo "${part_Q[@]}" | sed 's/[^ ]* [^ ]* /&\n/g'
```